# Why is the array not popping? (Why is it leaving trails or red color)

Tags: javascript

In the markup, the only canvas is present so there is no need of inserting the HTML. The problem is that the snake should move without leaving the red behind!

So if you in the JS section what I am trying to do is to move the head by adding a box to the array snake and then remove the head by popping the last element from the array.

When seen in the console the array seems to be only one element that means the snake.pop() is working fine. But for some reason, if you play it down below you'll see that the snake actually leaves those red boxes behind. Why is that happening?

```js
// Definitions
let box = 20;   // Unit for one box
let game = true;   // Game state
let score = 0;  // Score of the player

// Snake
let snake = [];
snake[0] = {
    x: 14 * box,
    y: 15 * box 
};

// Initialize
function init() {   // Function is called in the markup at <canvas>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('board');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
    // Drawing the Score Board
    ctx.fillStyle = '#212121';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,500,80);

    // Draw the snake
    for(let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = (i == 0) ? '#e84a5f' : '#ff847b';   // Color the head
        ctx.fillRect(snake[i].x , snake[i].y, box, box);
    }

    // Print the score
    // Food
    ctx.fillStyle = 'yellowgreen';
    ctx.fillRect(box, box, 2*box, 2*box); 
    // Score
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.font = '45px Raleway';
    ctx.fillText(score, 3.5*box, 2.65*box);

    // Randomnly create food
    ctx.fillStyle = 'yellowgreen'
    ctx.fillRect(Food.x, Food.y, box, box); 

    // Get previous head position
    let snakeX = snake[0].x;
    let snakeY = snake[0].y;

    // Add new according to the direction moving
    if (d == 'LEFT') snakeX -= box;
    if (d == 'UP') snakeY -= box;
    if (d == 'RIGHT') snakeX += box;
    if (d == 'DOWN') snakeY += box;

    // Remove tail of the snake
    snake.pop(); 

    // Define new head of snake
    let newSnakeHead = {
        x: snakeX,
        y: snakeY
    };

    snake.unshift(newSnakeHead);    // Add new head to snake
};

// Food Object; generates random x and y positions
let Food = {
    x: Math.floor(Math.random() * 24 + 1) * box,
    y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 24 + 4) * box   
};

// Snake Control
let d;
document.addEventListener('keydown', direction);
function direction(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 37 && d != 'RIGHT') {
        d = 'LEFT';
    } else if(event.keyCode == 38 && d != 'DOWN') {
        d = 'UP';
    } else if(event.keyCode == 39 && d != 'LEFT') {
        d = 'RIGHT';
    } else if(event.keyCode == 40 && d != 'UP') {
        d = 'DOWN';
    } 
};

// Game state
if (game) {
    let gameCall = setInterval(init, 100);
}
```

```css
#board {
    background-color: #323232;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Snake</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body onload="init();">
    <canvas id="board" width="500px" height="580px"></canvas>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest explanation is that the background isn't being redrawn after the snake's head has passed. Rather than redraw the entire canvas background, you can simply use the last part of the snake to draw the background in if you adjust the fill style in your drawing to include the background as well as the head and body.

I understand that this is a work-in-progress, so the most minimal changes I can suggest to demonstrate this are the inclusion of an expected length for the snake.

```
let expectedLength = 2; // EXPECTED LENGTH OF SNAKE
```

The adjustment of the colour choice for drawing the snake:

```
// COLOUR SNAKE SEGMENT
ctx.fillStyle = (i == 0) ? '#e84a5f' : (i >= expectedLength) ? '#323232' : '#ff847b';
```

The conditional removal of the tail:

```
// Remove tail of the snake (IF GREATER THAN EXPECTED LENGTH)
if (snake.length > expectedLength)
    snake.pop();
```

And finally the conditional addition of a new head (i.e. only if the snake is moving).

```
// Define new head of snake (IF SNAKE IS MOVING)
if ((snakeX != snake[0].x) || (snakeY != snake[0].y)) {
    let newSnakeHead = {
```

It's a bit more than a one-line tweak to your example, but it seemed liek the smallest sub0set I could add to make the section you had so far behave the way you might expect.

The full listing of app.js with those adjustments would therefore be:-

```
// Definitions
let box = 20;   // Unit for one box
let game = true;   // Game state
let score = 0;  // Score of the player

// Snake
let snake = [];
snake[0] = {
    x: 14 * box,
    y: 15 * box 
};
let expectedLength = 2; // EXPECTED LENGTH OF SNAKE

// Initialize
function init() {   // Function is called in the markup at <canvas>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('board');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
    // Drawing the Score Board
    ctx.fillStyle = '#212121';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,500,80);

    // Draw the snake
    for(let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
        // COLOUR SNAKE SEGMENT
        ctx.fillStyle = (i == 0) ? '#e84a5f' : (i >= expectedLength) ? '#323232' : '#ff847b';
        ctx.fillRect(snake[i].x , snake[i].y, box, box);
    }

    // Print the score
    // Food
    ctx.fillStyle = 'yellowgreen';
    ctx.fillRect(box, box, 2*box, 2*box); 
    // Score
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.font = '45px Raleway';
    ctx.fillText(score, 3.5*box, 2.65*box);

    // Randomnly create food
    ctx.fillStyle = 'yellowgreen'
    ctx.fillRect(Food.x, Food.y, box, box); 

    // Get previous head position
    let snakeX = snake[0].x;
    let snakeY = snake[0].y;

    // Add new according to the direction moving
    if (d == 'LEFT') snakeX -= box;
    if (d == 'UP') snakeY -= box;
    if (d == 'RIGHT') snakeX += box;
    if (d == 'DOWN') snakeY += box;

    // Remove tail of the snake (IF GREATER THAN EXPECTED LENGTH)
    if (snake.length > expectedLength)
        snake.pop(); 

    // Define new head of snake (IF SNAKE IS MOVING)
    if ((snakeX != snake[0].x) || (snakeY != snake[0].y)) {
        let newSnakeHead = {
            x: snakeX,
            y: snakeY
        };

        snake.unshift(newSnakeHead);    // Add new head to snake
    }
};

// Food Object; generates random x and y positions
let Food = {
    x: Math.floor(Math.random() * 24 + 1) * box,
    y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 24 + 4) * box   
};

// Snake Control
let d;
document.addEventListener('keydown', direction);
function direction(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 37 && d != 'RIGHT') {
        d = 'LEFT';
    } else if(event.keyCode == 38 && d != 'DOWN') {
        d = 'UP';
    } else if(event.keyCode == 39 && d != 'LEFT') {
        d = 'RIGHT';
    } else if(event.keyCode == 40 && d != 'UP') {
        d = 'DOWN';
    } 
};

// Game state
if (game) {
    let gameCall = setInterval(init, 100);
}
```

Comment: I figured it out myself LOL. But still thanks a lot for this!